# Weak quasi-completion of a locally convex space

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, dual-spaces, complete-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a locally convex space.
Then as far as I understand the bidual of $X$ with the weak topology, $(X_\beta')_\sigma'$, is like a quasi-completion of $X_\sigma$.
Namely, if $B \subseteq X$ is weakly bounded, then $\bar{B} \subseteq (X_\beta')_\sigma'$ is complete.
My question is then if $(X_\beta')_\sigma'$ itself is quasi-complete?

Comment: If we could prove that every closed and bounded subset of $(X'_\beta)'_\sigma$ is equicontinuous on $X'_\beta$, then it would be easy as we know these are complete for any polar topology. This was my idea, but I was not able to prove it.

Comment: What do $\beta$ and $\sigma$ indicate?

Comment: The topology, so $X_\sigma = (X, \sigma(X, X'))$, $X'_\beta = (X', \beta(X', X))$ and $(X'_\beta)'_\sigma = (Y', \sigma(Y', Y))$ where $Y = X'_\beta$. Also, $\beta(X', X)$ is the topology of uniform convergence on bounded sets, and $\sigma(Y', Y)$ is the topology of pointwise convergence, a.k.a. the weak topology.

Comment: There are even Fréchet spaces $X$ such that the strong dual is not (quasi-) barrelled, $X$ is then called **non-distinguished**. This seems to be related to your question although I don't know if the bidual is then quasi-incomplete in the weak$^*$ topology.

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting. So then it is definitely true for distinguished spaces, but might not be true for non-distinguished spaces. Since my suspicion is that it is in general not true, then I now know where I should look for counterexamples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jochen for pointing me in the direction where to look I was able to find a reference for a counterexample.
In "Sur les Espaces (F) et (DF)", Summa Brasil. Math. 3 (1954), at p. 88 Grothendieck gives an example of a non-distinguished space $E$ where $E''$ is not weakly quasi-complete.

Comment: Exellent. It's always good to read the old masters.